# Hello, how to give CSS for class or ID worked in all app in ionic onclick or onchange function?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

```
<ion-select class="custom-options" (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
<ion-select-option selected value="pink">pink</ion-select-option>
<ion-select-option value="green">green</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

When the user select pink I want to give some classes or ids CSS color or background color how can I make a function like this

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to do this (not the only one) is by accessing the html document from my ts file, like this:

1st, in your html file define an id for every 'ion-select-option' (ex. id="1"). Then modify its content when the (ionChange) method is called (in your case was "onChange($event)").

```
onChange($event){
  document.getElementById('1').classList.add('custom-css-class')
}
```

Then define a css class in your file.scss file with the same name and it should work fine like that.